# Removing certain identical lines of text from a large number of documents, automatically

Tags: text, document

I have around 2000 .PHP documents with unwanted text in each. The unwanted text is identical in each document and occurs on the same lines. I'd like to know whether it'd be possible to delete these lines from every text document, automatically? As opposed to having to manually delete them from every file.

I googled for 'Automator workflows' for OS X, no luck here. I didn't find an AppleScript solution either. Honestly, I'm not very tech savvy, I just know markup language.. so please keep this in mind if you are kind enough to answer.

Thanks very much for your time,
Teebs

Comment: First thing that comes to mind for me is using a text editor that has the ability to "replace in files". Point it at a directory, give it the search text and replace it with an empty string and let it rip (after you've backed everything up, of course).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with find + perl, with something like (didn't test it, so do test it first):

```
find /where/your/files/are -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -pi.bak -e 's/the-line-you-dont-want//g'
```

See "man perlrun" for the "-p" option.  Note that you can put replacement text between the "//".  The xargs and print0 allow you to cope with the long command line 2000 file would present.  The ".bak" makes backups of everything with ".bak" added to the end, which might or might not be advantageous.   I'm paranoid, so I'd probably copy just the PHP files to a 2nd and 3rd directory, then run the command with find /the/2nd/one ... (without the ".bak" part), then use a recursive diff to see all the edits (diff -r /the/3rd/one /the/2nd/one).  If happy, then run it on the /where/your/files/are

If the text crosses multiple lines, it's still possible to do it in one pass by adding "s" to the "g" option of the s/ command.  Docs are in "man perlre", under modifiers.